# Display date in JTextField

Tags: java

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Date udoa = new Date(calendar.getTime().getTime());`
```

Here, I am storing system date in `udoa` (local variable)

I want to display it in `JTextField doa;`

`doa.setText(udoa);`

I am using this, but it is not working because data type of `udoa` is date.

Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Use a SimpleDateFormat formatter. Consider using a JFormattedTextField that uses the SimpleDateFormat as its formatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by using the `toString()` Method of Date

use `doa.setText(udoa.toString());`